# Fetch navbar elements from SQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mySQL table containing stores. It looks like this:

```
id | name   | city
1  | H&M    | New York
2  | Gucci  | New York
3  | H&M    | Chicago
4  | H&M    | Boston
5  | Gucci  | Las Vegas
6  | Cavalli| New York
7  | H&M    | Phoenix
```

I have a drop-down menu that I want to be looking like this:

- Home
- Stores

  - New York
  - Chicago
  - Boston
  - Las Vegas
  - Phoenix

My question is: How do I fetch, **without repeating**, the cities I have stores in so I can make each of them a hyperlink in my drop-down menu like this: `mypage.com/city/new-york`. The page it will lead to, will obviously contain the stores `where city='$_GET['city']'`.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT city FROM ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use    `DISTINCT`
this will help to optimize data [MORE INFO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html)

**Syntax:**

`SELECT DISTINCT column FROM Table_name`

also you can use multiple columns

**Syntax:**

`SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM t1`

Comment: Had not heard of this one. Worked great. Thanks!